# Using CAS, memcached and load balancing to make CAS Highly Available

Tags: java, memcached, cas, amazon-elb, spymemcached

I am using CAS server (veresion 3.4.8) and trying to deploy it in HA environment. I have used memcached as CAS's ticketRegistry and using Amazon's ELB for load balancing. I have done the configurations as mentioned in https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/MemcacheTicketRegistry for CAS 3.4.x . I have also configured session affinity/ sticky session that Amazon's ELB has to offer. Both the CAS servers are deployed fine and  both the memcached nodes (I have deployed one memcached node with each of the CAS servers and configured the ticketRegistry to use both of them as mentioned in the link above) as also deployed fine and when I try to browse my application using CAS I always get redirected to CAS's login page. The problem starts when a multiple users start using it (around 10 to 20). The user get authenticated and redirected to the application sometimes and sometimes the same user do not get to login. In both the cases TGT and ST gets created in the CAS server, but when the ST is sent to the application by CAS (through the browser) the ST never comes back to CAS for validation and the user gets redirected to the following URL of the application. https://my.application.that.uses.cas/login/authfail?login_error=1 (We use a grails app with spring security cas/core) with a status 404. This happens after CAS redirects to the application with the service ticket. https://my.application.that.uses.cas/j_spring_cas_security_check?ticket=ST-1417-6gldTBUNrTjUFeSe0BVh-cas.

When I turn one of the EC2 instances off, all the users start getting authenticated everytime. This also happens for proxy tickets as we're using it for web service authentication. Sometimes the proxy ticket gets created and validated and sometimes it does not in the same session for that user.  Am I missing something here? Does this look like an issue related to memcached or it looks like a load balancer issue? Any help would be highly appreciated!

NOTE: I have configured the TGT expiration time to be 2 hours and ST expiration time to be 10 seconds in MemCacheTicketRegistry bean and I use the following command to start memcaced
memcached -d -u myUserName -m 512 -p 11211 0.0.0.0

Thanks,